# Spotting the coordinates where fireworks has light

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to spot the coordinates when someone light a firework, and save the coordinates that firework has been lighted. I tried to use *testfor*, but I see that it has been removed on 1.13.2. I am new to the JSON system. Can someone give me ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: If you try to use `testfor`, then you think about it wrong. :D It was mostly useless since 1.9 already. And why JSON? Please specify more what you actually tried. Would the spot where someone stands when firing a firework be fine, too?

Comment: You could use commands to summon armor stands at all fireworks without a certain tag, then tag them in the next command block. That would leave one, invisible armor stand "marker" where the firework was placed. Would that solve your problem if I told you how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Reddit and @SpiceWeasel , I solved it! I made smoke summoned on every fired firework, and made all other placements based to that smoke.

Comment: That's a really neat concept. Would you mind doing a brief write up of what exactly you did to make this happen, in case somebody else wants to replicate something similar?

Comment: 1) execute at @e[type=firework_rocket,tag=!processed] run summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:200,Tags:["Flare"]} 2) execute at @e[type=area_effect_cloud,tag=Flare] run particle minecraft:smoke ~ ~ ~ 0 1 0 0.01 5